# Assigning PHP variable to PHP array

Tags: javascript, php

I want to assign some php to a javascript variable like:

```
var goldPrice = <?php echo ResourceArray::$goldLevel[$user->getResource($data->id, "goldLevel")]?>;
```

but ends up with: 1 (instead of 2000).

Here's my troubleshooting:

I have an array in a php class:

```
<?php
class ResourceArray {
  public static $goldLevel = array(
   0, 2000, 10000
  ),
```

I've tried to assign through a couple of variables to find the problem with no luck:

```
var goldLevel = <?php $user->getResource($data -> id, "goldLevel") ?>;
var goldPrice = <?php echo ResourceArray::$goldLevel[$user->getResource($data->id, "goldLevel")]?>;
var goldPrice1 = <?php echo ResourceArray::$goldLevel[1]?>;
```

This writes:

```
var goldLevel = 1;
var goldPrice = 1;
var goldPrice1 = 2000;
```

Finally I tried to assign a php variable to put in:

```
PHP: $goldLevel1 = $user->getResource($data->id, "goldLevel");
     $goldLevel2 = 1;


js: var goldPrice2 = <?php echo ResourceArray::$goldLevel[$goldLevel1]?>;
    var goldPrice3 = <?php echo ResourceArray::$goldLevel[$goldLevel2]?>;
```

This ends up like:

```
var goldPrice2 = ;
var goldPrice3 = 2000;
```

When I echo $goldLevel1 and $goldLevel2, it shows 1 and 1.

Comment: I would start by `var_dump($user->getResource($data->id, "goldLevel"))`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying this works fine with me:

```
<html><body>
<?php

class ResourceArray {
  public static $goldLevel = array(
   0, 2000, 10000
  );
}

// set gold price to second entry of goldLevel array
$goldPrice = ResourceArray::$goldLevel[1];
// check to make sure we have a valid number
if (!is_numeric($goldPrice) || $goldPrice < 1)
    $goldPrice = 0;

// this outputs 2000
echo $goldPrice;

?>
<script>
    var goldPrice = <?php echo $goldPrice; ?>;
    alert(goldPrice);
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

Try using json_encode()

[Documentation for json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Use it like this

```
var goldPrice = <?php echo json_encode(array(0, 2000, 10000))?>;
```

Just replace the array for the dynamically created one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a variable of json

```
 var jsonO = <?php echo json_encode(array(0, 2000, 10000))?>;
```

this will be a json string, convert it to javascript array

```
var goldPrice = $.map(jsonO, function(el) { return el; })
```

then use goldPrice array.